# How to traverse through list of components inside ViewContainerRef?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm trying to implement key board navigation on a list of components present inside `ViewContainerRef`, without knowing how many components are actually present.

Current approach: Right now while adding components in ViewContainerRef, I'm storing component index inside view and ComponentRef together as a object in a list i.e:

```
{ component : ComponentRef<any>, index: number }
```

I'm getting index by doing `indexOf` on `ViewContainerRef`. 
     For key board navigation , I'm listening to events and traversing through the list I created I above and keeping track of what's currently selected component. 
 Can this be  done in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

`ViewContainerRef` has the getters `length` and `get` (`[]`)

```
selectedIndex:number = 0;

cursorUp() {
  if(this.selectedIndex > 0) {
    this.selectedIndex--;
  }
  console.log('selectedComponent', this.vcRef[this.selectedIndex]);
}

cursorDown() {
  if(this.selectedIndex < this.vcRef.length - 1) {
    this.selectedIndex++;
  }
  console.log('selectedComponent', this.vcRef[this.selectedIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Doing get on ViewContainerRef would give me a ViewRef, which is useful only if I want to attach or detach it from the view. It won't provide a way to call a function inside selectedComponent.

Comment: I see. In this case I think an approach like shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 makes this much easier and I think it's more like Angular should be used - less imperative DOM manipulation - more model-driven and the DOM updated by directives.

Comment: I'm using similar approach as given in the answer , except that i don't have predefined list of component types. So I pass around ComponentRef instead.

Comment: I guess there is no way around keeping `ComponentRef`s around yourself